# Using Trello Batch API call with Query Params

Tags: api, trello

Is there a way to use the Trello [batch API method](https://developers.trello.com/reference#batch) when the URL's being batched contain query parameters?

For example

```
https://api.trello.com/1/batch/?urls=/boards/XXXXX/members,/boards/XXXXX/lists/open?cards=open&fields=name&card_fields=name,idMembers&key=123&token=789
```

Comment: Hi, did you by any chance found if this works? trying myself exactly the same board lists request but it always returns same result for the first route and ignores the rest...

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I ended up making a bunch of single calls.

Answer (score 1):

So I recently faced this issue and this is post I found as first result in google. For me encoding commas did not work. I figured out a solution that worked though.

You can pass multiple request parameters - that if not for batch requests you would simply separate by commas - by passing them as array.

Example for batch request:

**Not working**

```
https://api.trello.com/1/batch/?urls=
/boards/XXXXX?fields=name,id,members,
/boards/YYYYY?fields=name,id,members
```

**Working solution**

```
https://api.trello.com/1/batch/?urls=
/boards/XXXXX?fields=name&fields=id&fields=members,
/boards/YYYYY?fields=name&fields=id&fields=members
```

That way commas are only in places that api expects it (separating each GET request).
Unfortunalety the more I work with Trello API the more I see how incomplete it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. You have to run your `urls` parameter through `encodeUriComponent`, so result URL looks like this:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/batch?urls=%2Fboards%2FXXXXX%2Fmembers,%2Fboards%2FXXXXX%2Flists%2Fopen%3Fcards%3Dopen%26fields%3Dname%26card_fields%3Dname,idMembers&key=123&token=789
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the query parameter contains commas.  The API trips up at `card_fields%3Dname,idMembers` saying that `1/idMembers` isn't a route.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was fairly simple.
Replace all commas within individual queries with '&&'

```
/1/batch/?urls=
  /boards/XXXXX/members,
  /boards/XXXXX/lists/open?cards=open&fields=name&card_fields=name&&idMembers&keyAndToken
```